# How click method of webelement works internally?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am new to selenium so I was going through **selenium documentation** and in **documentation** below is the description for click() method:

**Click()**

Click this element. If this causes a new page to load, you should discard all references to this element and any further operations performed on this element will throw a StaleElementReferenceException. Note that if click() is done by sending a native event (which is the default on most browsers/platforms) then the method will *not* wait for the next page to load and the caller should verify that themselves.

Can anyone please help me in understanding what does these above explaination exactly mean?
It will be a big help if provided a supporting example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to invoke the .click() method that selenium provides when you have for example a button that you want to click. Now for the part " If this causes a new page to load, you should discard all references to this element and any further operations performed on this element will throw a StaleElementReferenceException" this is telling you that if your click on this particular button causes for example a popup to appear then selenium does not switch automatically to that popup , you have to include that into your code. If you don't do so and try to click on the element in the popup then you will get Exception. Furthermore, the last part is stating that when you initially click on the button, selenium does not explicitly wait for the popup to load. You have to tell selenium to wait for that popup in case you want to perform some actions on it, like verify label or get data etc...
Hope this helped clarify the things a little bit.
Good luck. Selenium is FUN

Comment: thanks for the response can you please recommend me video tutorials or any type tutorials?

Comment: Check a youtube channel called "Automation Step by Step". You should be good with selenium and Frameworks after you are done with his Tutorials. Please consider upvoting my answer if you think it was useful to you.Thanks